# jquery show() function not working with appendTo

Tags: jquery

```
$('input[type="text"]').keypress(function(event){
  if(event.which === 13) {
    var inputValue = $(this).val();
    var appendli = "<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span> " + inputValue + "</li>";

    $(appendli).appendTo('ul').show();
    $(this).val("");
  }
});
```

When i append the li to the ul,show() is not working nor any other effects like slideDown . Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *I've inserted animation time in  show() but still not working.

Comment: I used .hide() before appendTo and now its working perfectly!